# Materialized views - Oracle

Tags: oracle

On dropping the Materialized view, What happens to the reports (SQLs) based on that Materialized view.
Is there any table with same name as MView which can still serve data to the SQLs

Thanks ..

Comment: AFAIK, when a materialized view is dropped in an Oracle database, it means that the materialized view object is permanently removed from the database. Any reports or SQL queries that were based on that materialized view will no longer be able to retrieve data from it...

Comment: If only the mview definition is dropped, not the underlying table, you can still use the table. But if the underlying table is dropped (default), your data is gone. Keep in mind that an mview is merely a SQL query that materializes the result for quicker access, and all its source data comes from elsewhere. You don't actually need mviews - you can write the underlying SQL and run it directly with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Reports will stop working (obviously) as source "table" (materialized view in your case) doesn't exist any more. You'll get ORA-00942 error.

There's no other table *with same name*; that's impossible as you can't even have two tables with the same name in the same schema. *Maybe*, just *maybe* if there was a public synonym with that name (pointing to table/view/materialized view with the same description and data), then yes - report would keep working.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`PRESERVE TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DROP-MATERIALIZED-VIEW.html) addition when dropping MV.